# Logging to 2 log files using 2 loggers is duplicating the logs (using log4j)

Tags: java, log4j

I am trying to create 2 log files using log4j using this configuration:

```
log4j.rootLogger=debug,stdout,logfile
#debug info warn error fatal 

# Set the enterprise logger category to FATAL and its only appender to CONSOLE.
log4j.logger.org.apache=FATAL,logfile

# ConsoleAppender properties
log4j.appender.stdout=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.stdout.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.stdout.Threshold=debug
log4j.appender.stdout.layout.ConversionPattern=%d %5p %c{1}:%L - %m%n
#%-5p [%t]: %m%n

# LogFileAppender properties
log4j.appender.logfile=com.xx.util.SizeRollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.logfile.File=log.log
log4j.appender.logfile.MaxFileSize=50240KB
log4j.appender.logfile.BackupsDirectory=log
log4j.appender.logfile.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.logfile.layout.ConversionPattern=%d %5p %c{1}:%L - %m%n
log4j.appedner.logfile.Threshold=error


# Log1FileAppender properties
log4j.appender.log1=com.xx.util.SizeRollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.log1.File=log1.log
log4j.appender.log1.MaxFileSize=5120KB
log4j.appender.log1.BackupsDirectory=log
log4j.appender.log1.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.log1.layout.ConversionPattern=%d %5p %c{1} :%L - %m%n
```

(the xx is for the project that I am working on) -

And here it is the Java Code:

```
public class TestLog4j {

/**
 * @param args
 */
private static org.apache.log4j.Logger log              = org.apache.log4j.Logger.getLogger(TestLog4j.class);
private static org.apache.log4j.Logger log1= org.apache.log4j.Logger.getLogger("log1");

public static void main(String[] args) {

    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    org.apache.log4j.PropertyConfigurator.configure("src/com/test/log4j.properties");
    log.error("Error Test Log");
    log1.info("Test Log1");
}

}
```

My problem is that I want to write two different files, one for log and one for log1. What I am getting with this code is only one file being created with both logs in the same file.

What I am doing wrong?

Comment: Can you clarify what you want to achieve? So, which log messages from where should go into which logfile?
Point is: You are instantiating a Logger for "log1", but you dont have any logger defined with that name! You just have a rootLogger and a logger named "org.apache", but no "log1"...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Short answer:

Add:

```
log4j.logger.log1=<yourLogLevel>,log1
```

to your log4j.properties.

**NOTE:**

Every enabled log-request to log1 (log-level >= yourLogLevel) will go to both `stdout` **and** `logfile` unless you turn off appender-additivity!